# Getting interior elements of a 2D array only

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix like the below:

```
test_numpy_array = np.array([[2,3,4,5],
                             [6,4,1,2],
                             [3,4,5,1],
                             [8,9,7,6],
                             [4,1,2,5]])
```

How do I extract only the interior numbers, such that they have 8 neighbors for an array of any size?

Comment: Delete first and last lists, and remove indexes 0 and -1 for the remaining lists

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I am later looking to compare an interior element with its 8 neighbors to find if its a local minimum.

Comment: @Jon, if one of the answers below helped, feel free to accept one (tick on left) so that other users can see a tested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for help regarding determination of whether each element is a local minimum, you should probably edit your original post to reflect that.

Regardless, here's some code to push you in the right direction for that.  Not sure if you wanted to print, or get a 2D boolean area or what, but this should get you close enough.

```
def is_local_min(a, r, c):
    for i in range(r-1, r+2):
        for j in range(c-1, c+2):
            if i == r and j == c:
                continue
            if a[i][j] < a[r][c]:
                return False
    return True


def get_local_mins(arr):
    local_mins = []
    for i in range(1, np.shape(arr)[0]-1):
        for j in range(1, np.shape(arr)[1]-1):
            if is_local_min(arr, i, j):
                local_mins.append((i, j))
    return local_mins
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
test_numpy_array[1:-1, 1:-1]
```